# Appengine + Hibernate OMG - how to make it work?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, google-app-engine

I am trying to get a very simple example running with the Jetty Dev Server that comes with the Eclipse plugin. So far no luck.

Code:

```
This is the code:
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
EntityManager entityManager;

entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "hike-PU" );
entityManager=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Person p = new Person("Peter");

entityManager.persist(p);

Hike mountKillMore=new Hike("mountKillmore Flat", "Palm Springs");
mountKillMore.organizer=p;  
p.organizedHikes.add(mountKillMore);

Hike rushDuddeldei=new Hike("rushDudeldidei Down", "Rush Upstream");
rushDuddeldei.organizer=p;  
p.organizedHikes.add(rushDuddeldei);

entityManager.persist(p);
entityManager.persist(mountKillMore);
entityManager.persist(rushDuddeldei);

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

entityManagerFactory.close();
```

And here is the error stacktrace I am getting:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
at org.hibernate.ogm.transaction.impl.OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.(OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.java:31)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator.prepareServices(OgmIntegrator.java:161)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributingIntegrators(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:264)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:248)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1025)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:837)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:62)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
at moe.bang.YTAnotherGoServlet.doGet(YTAnotherGoServlet.java:19)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:503)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createSecurityManager")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory$CallerProvider.(LoggerFactory.java:24)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory$CallerProvider.(LoggerFactory.java:24)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory.(LoggerFactory.java:18)
... 56 more
Caused by:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createSecurityManager")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory$CallerProvider.(LoggerFactory.java:24)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory$CallerProvider.(LoggerFactory.java:24)
at org.hibernate.ogm.util.impl.LoggerFactory.(LoggerFactory.java:18)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
at org.hibernate.ogm.transaction.impl.OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.(OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.java:31)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator.prepareServices(OgmIntegrator.java:161)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributingIntegrators(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:264)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:248)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1025)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:837)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:62)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
at moe.bang.YTAnotherGoServlet.doGet(YTAnotherGoServlet.java:19)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:503)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My first guess was that I might be running into a whitelisting issue for the loaded classes. Reason being, the exact same code works perfectly fine for a standalone client using the same persistence unit, JARs.

What do you think? Can I somehow overcome this: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission") ?

Comment: standalone client != appengine runtime. see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: But Hibernate is know to work, not sure about your exact issue. Or you connecting to CloudsQL or the datastore or other ?

Comment: I am connecting to Mongolab. Note that I am using Hibernate OmG